# What is the best way to check if a subclass is of a specific type?

Tags: c#, oop, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a `Person` base class and three derivatives. On the edit page I have a section with general person data (name, address, etc.).

I also want a section per subclass. So if a `Person` is a `User` I want to add a section with the specific user data. If a `Person` is also a `CardHolder` I want to show the card holder section.

I am struggling on how to implement this. What I have in mind is to ask the `UserRepository` if the specified `Person` is a `User`. If so, the method will return a `User` object; otherwise null. I am planning to do this for all the subclasses.

However, I have this feeling that this can be done a better way, but I can't find that way.

**EDIT:**
I have the following scenario. I have an overview with `Person` objects (not the derivatives!). When a row is clicked, I want to show the details page. On this page I have the different sections as described above. At this point I want to know if the 'Person' is also a `User` or a 'Cardholder'.

I'd like to apply polymorphism, but I don't see how...

Comment: If you're doing logic based on the type of an object, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Jason How would you implement this?

Comment: I'd use this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Comment: @Jason I have edited my post, can I still use method overriding? If so, can you explain to me how?

Comment: @Martijn See my answer it could help.

Comment: @Fuex, you are not using method overriding which he is asking for in the comment. To use polymorphism see my answer.

Comment: @Fuex - also your method won't work because he has introduced a one to many relationship.  Because of this a single enum cannot hold values in the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have an abstract function on the Person class called something like "`ReturnValidSectionsForPerson()`".  In each subclass, override that function to return "`UserData`" or "`CardHolder`" as appropriate.  You can use an enumeration to hold the various types of sections to make it easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thnx, but I am wondering how to implement this. I have an overview with `Person` objects, then I click a row and go to the details screen. At the details screen I have the `Person` object. At this point I want to know what kind of person the person more is (A person can be a cardholder but it can also be a user).

Comment: I think you're looking at it backwards.  You don't want to know that the person is a cardholder or is a user;  you want to know if the person should have a UserData or a CardholderDetails section.  My advise boils down to 'ask the person'.  By having this function on the class itself, you can have each subclass (or even instance of the subclass depending on the logic required) specify exactly what sections it requires.

Comment: But when I am in the details page, I only have access to the `Person` object. When I call `ReturnValidSectionsForPerson()` I will get only the person section..

Comment: Not exactly.  Since the two other classes derive from `Person` and override the `ReturnValidSectionsForPerson` method, even though you only see them as `Person`, they actually exist as `User` or `Cardholder`, and their overriding functions will be called.

Comment: But I call `PersonRepository.GetAll()`. This method returns a List of `Person` objects. I call this method in the overview page. So when I click on a row, I see the details page and the `Person` object is send to that page. So, when I call `ReturnValidSectionsForPerson()` I still have the person section and not the others, right?

Comment: Oh, this is coming out of some repository.  That does change things slightly;  I would suggest that you add a column that contains an enumerated value specifying the subtype of Person at the time that the Repository is populated, and call the appropriate subtype constructors when pulling from the Repository.  Exactly how to do that is more dependent on your ORM, so its hard to be specific.

Comment: Hehe, the extra column won't work, because a `Person` can be a `User` and a `Cardholder` and maybe in the future it can be more roles..

Comment: So what you mean is that the subtypes are not mutually exclusive?  At that point I would be inclined to simply separate the concerns and say that a `Person` class has a property which is a subcollection of `Role`s, and approach the problem from that perspective.

Comment: Yes, someone can be a Person, a User and a Cardholder. What do you mean with 'a Person class has a property which is a subcollection of Roles' It's not strictly a role like an Administrator, it is more what the user is or can be.

Comment: Martijn - If they can have any role add them to an `IList`.

Comment: @JonH What do you mean by 'If they have any role' Do you suggest to introduce an interface?

Comment: Martijn from what you have a posted a person can be a user, can be a card holder, can be a ..., can be a ....  You cannot just use an enum type due to this type of relationship.  You have introduced a one to many relationship because not only can the person be a single "user" or "cardholder" they can now be both.  How do you store multiple types to one person?  You need a list to do so right?

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. So you suggest to create a List on the Person class and when mapping (read fill) this list, fill it with all the types the Person is. Right?

Comment: Marijn - you know your business logic more then I do, I can only try to guide you.  From what you have stated there exists some sort of one to many relationship.  Knowing just this tells me you cannot use a single enum / variable to store the type.  Because you have a one to many relationship you need a container to store these results.  Enter the List/IList

Comment: @JonH can you post an answer with your List explained? Then I can check that answer as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there are three things you can do in increasing order of preference.

1) Use "is" to explicitly check the class of the object.  The problem with this approach is that it's brittle.  If you come up with new subclasses in the future you need to change your condition.  This breaks the "open/closed principle":  you shouldn't need to modify code that exists in order to add new features.

2) Implement a "hasDetails" method in Person and override it in User.  You then check "hasDetails" which you can then implement in any class that implements that interface.  This is preferable because it allows you to add new code without changing existing code but is inflexible because it assumes that all details are the same.

3) "Tell, don't ask".  Don't ask the object for information about itself and do something based on the result.  Instead, tell the object to do the operation itself.  This allows the object to decide when to do it and how to do it.

Using #3 is preferable in most cases but there are situations where you really have no choice but to go with #2 (eg. packaging or layering requires that the operation you want to perform can't be done by the Person object) or even with #1 (eg. you don't have access to the source code of the Person class or can't add methods to it).

Comment: Thans for the answer, but I can't use any of them. The problem is that I have an overview with only `Person` objects (these are fetched from the `PersonRepository`). So when I am on the details page, I only have the `Person` object. When I use the `is` operator, it will always return false because other types are never loaded.

Comment: Can you explain your class hierarchy so I can better understand?  Are User and CardHolder subclasses of Person?  If so, I think the issue is that your PersonRepository is only returning instances of the superclass Person instead of the proper subclass.  Then again, perhaps I just don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes that is correct, the overview only shows `Person` objects. It can't show anything else because a `Person` can also be a `User` and also a `Cardholder`

Comment: This sounds like more of a ui issue then anything.  If these persons can contain a "user" and / or a cardholder status, this is a one to many relationship.  Store the relationships in some sort of List.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `is` operator:

```
if(Person is User) { /* do something */ }
if(Person is CardHolder) { /* do something more */ }
```

Read more  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

As Jason commented, you probably want to do something else like this:

```
interface class Person
{
    IEnumerable<Section> GetSections();
}

class User : Person
{
     IEnumerable<Section> GetSections() { return new[] { new PersonSection() }; }
}

class CardHolder : Person
{
     IEnumerable<Section> GetSections() 
     { 
          return base.GetSections().Concat(new [] {new CardHolderSection() });
     }
}
```

Comment: This type of logic is the wrong way to do polymorphism. At a minimum, it's a nightmare to maintain. What happens if you have a new type? Or you end up with a large hierarchy of different types. Yucky.

Comment: @Jason, I agree that you should probably use something else to solve the problem but that is not always possible, and sometimes if you are in a legacy code base that might be the only way to go at the moment. Also, the question is still "What is the best way to check if a subclass is of a specific type?", and using the `is` operator is the way to do exactly that. What you are pointing out is something else. So if you are the one downvoting I think you did so for the wrong reason.

Comment: The question ends with "However, I have this feeling that this can be done a better way, but I can't find that way." which you didn't address at all.

Comment: @Jason: But that doesn't make the answer less correct. It is not complete, but it is now wrong. But I took you comment in mind and updated my answer.

Comment: @Jason - instead of downvoting why don't you provide a solution since you are being very critical in your comments.  This is not worthy of a downvote, but your comments are...unfortunately we cannot downvote your comments.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: I don't agree. It's the wrong way to do things, and answers that proliferate the wrong way of thinking should not be encouraged. That said, I have removed my downvote and even upvoted because you edited your answer and incorporated a more useful way of looking at the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @TomasJansson I like your idea, but I think I can't use this approach. I have edited my startpost (the part about the overview).

Comment: @JonH: We will just have to agree to disagree. If it's wrong, it gets a downvote. I consider answers that proliferate a wrong way of thinking about this problem to be wrong. Therefore, they get a downvote.

Comment: @Martijn, I think it might be a little bit tricky to use polymorphism in you scenario since you have your data from the UI and not from the repository. My guess is that you are using a relation database which make the polymorphism even harder to do. The most effective way might be to use an `enum` on your `Person` objects and return secions based on that `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

just make use of `is` operator - The is operator is used to check whether the run-time type of an object is compatible with a given type. The is operator is used in an expression of the form:

```
if(pers is user )
{
}
else if (pers is cardholder)
{
}
```

Comment: This type of logic is the wrong way to do polymorphism. At a minimum, it's a nightmare to maintain. What happens if you have a new type? Or you end up with a large hierarchy of different types. Yucky.

Comment: @Jason - agree i m searching for solution which deals with generic method ...wait if i found will edit here

Answer (score 1):

`typeof (SubClass).IsSubclassOf(typeof (BaseClass));` // returns true

Comment: This type of logic is the wrong way to do polymorphism. At a minimum, it's a nightmare to maintain. What happens if you have a new type? Or you end up with a large hierarchy of different types. Yucky.

Comment: @Jason - provide your idea then.

Comment: Why? GWLlosa already gave a perfectly fine answer which I upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use aggregation instead of inheritance. Make properties `Person.UserData` and `Person.CardholderDetails` and show/hide controls depending on whether corresponsing property is 'null' or not.

Comment: I like this approach, but then I have to create properties for each new derivative, right? And where/how do I fill these properties?

Comment: Yes -- property for every section you need to edit. And fill them like you fill regular properties of your subclasses :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but I think you should be able to do a "is" check:

```
var isUser = myObject is User;
```

See the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

EDIT:

This is a simple solution, and will require maintenance if more classes are added. Please refer to other solutions for a better answer.

Hope it helps,

Christian

Comment: This type of logic is the wrong way to do polymorphism. At a minimum, it's a nightmare to maintain. What happens if you have a new type? Or you end up with a large hierarchy of different types. Yucky.

Comment: @Jason - save yourself time, at the header is the comments section.  You can generalize your comment ONCE their instead of adding the same comment multiple times.  Please read the FAQ.

Comment: @JonH: Don't agree. I downvoted this post. I always leave a comment on the post when I downvote.

Comment: @Jason While I agree that this isn't the most elegant solution, it is a simple solution. I'll add a cavaet about the short comings of this answer. Wont update further, as others have provided better answers.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following scenario. I have an overview with Person objects
>   (not the derivatives!). When a row is clicked, I want to show the
>   details page. On this page I have the different sections as described
>   above. At this point I want to know if the 'Person' is also a `User`
>   or a `Cardholder`.

You can use [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
So you can do something like this:

```
[Flags]    
public enum Test
{
    User,
    CardHolder
}
```

And then use it in your class:

```
public class Person
{
    //...
    public Test MyTest;
}
```

So then you can use it wherever you want:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Test1 = (Test.User | Test.CardHolder);

//...

if(person.MyTest == Test.User | Test.CardHolder))
{
     //Do something
}
```

Or simply:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Test1 = Test.User;

//...

if(person.MyTest == Test.User)
{
     //Do something
}

if(person.MyTest == Test.CardHolder)
{ 
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: this is doable but I would consider use polymorphism as I suggest in my solution. But good that you provide a different answer.

Comment: @Fuex what if he is both a cardholder and a user?